# Difference between these words

Tags: word

What's the difference between these pairs of words? My book doesn't give a clear distinction between them.

如果 - 要是

必须 - 要

报名 - 注册

查 - 检查

读书 - 看书

Answer (score 6):

These are similar terms just as their english counterparts:

如果 - In case
要是 - If

必须 - Necessary
要 - Need / require

报名 - Sign up
注册 - Register

查 - Check / Search
检查 - inspection

读书 - Reading (in terms of Studying)
看书 - Read a book

Answer (score 0):

要是
[yào shi]
if ； suppose ； in case

如果
[rú guǒ]
if ； in case ； in the event of ； supposing that ； in the event

汉语词语 词目：要是 拼音：yào shì 近义词：要是——如果 基本解释 [in case;if] ——用在偏正复句的偏句中，表示假设，相当于“如果”

Answer (score -3):

如果 - 要是: almost same, 如果 formal language, 要是 oral language.----

必须 - 要: 必须 is "must" very strong, 要 is "shall" not strong.----

报名 - 注册 same

查 - 检查 same, 查 is a short one of 检查

读书 - 看书  same